# Can Ubuntu Touch be flashed to a Flyme Meizu Pro 5 64G version?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I've seen a "howto" of flashing Ubuntu to a Flyme Meizu Pro 5. But can it be flashed to a Flyme Meizu Pro 5 64G version?